# How to import a public key via amazon aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to import a public key for a newly created user on the Amazon AWS console. Per the documentation, this is done as follows:

> 1. Click Key Pairs in the navigation pane.
> 2. Click Import Key Pair.
> 3. In the Import Key Pair dialog box, click Browse, and select the public key file that you saved previously. Enter a name for the key pair in the Key pair name field, and click Import.

However, I'm having trouble finding "Key Pairs". Where is it?

Comment: What terrible instructions. You don't import public keys, or key pairs, you import certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate a keypair first. If you are using unix `ssh-keygen` can generate a keypair for you. Just google for RSA keypair generation. Keep the private key with you and import the public key into AWS.

Comment: The key pair has already been generated by a third party. I just need to import the public key, but still haven't found the option to do so.

Comment: In EC2 dashboard, on the left pane, under Network & Security, click on `Key Pairs` and then import.

Comment: Thanks, I was on the AWS console - I had to drill down into EC2 services.